# Create bitmap from byte array received via Bluetooth and save bitmap in sdcard

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have to implement a code in which i am receiving byte array from external h/w. device and at my end I have to create a bitmap image from byte array and store that bitmap in sdcard.

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file.jpeg");

        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write(buffer);
            //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer , 0, buffer.length);

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

File is created in sdcard but that file is not showing image.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer , 0, buffer.length);
            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.jpg");
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

Comment: did you received correct data from bluetooth..???

Comment: Yes,I am receiving correct data from bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
FileInputStream in;    
BufferedInputStream buf;    
try {      
    in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/pictures/1.jpg");    
    buf = new BufferedInputStream(in,1070);    
    byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];   
    buf.read(bMapArray);     
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length); 
}catch (Exception e) {        
    Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());      
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Grishu but i am not using intent please suggest another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Let `image` contains Bitmap image

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

`imageInByte` now contains bytedata of bitmap image.

For converting reverse

`Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArray, 0,imgArray.length);`
Hope this may help you

**UPDATED :**

*Store the data on Sd Card*

```
Bitmap bmp = createBitmap();
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.jpg");
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

Comment: That's ok but i have to save this bitmap in sdcard also.

Comment: Please check my question again I have changed my code according to you but still i am there.

Comment: No,I am not getting any error.The file is creating successfully,But not showing image.